# Existance of function of norm one on normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

On a past exam in a course on functional analysis the following problem is given:

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and let $x\in X$ be nonzero. Show that there exist some $f\in X^\ast$ s.t. $f(x) = \|x\|$ and $\|f\|=1$.

Here $X^\ast$ denotes the dual of $X$.

I have a proof, although it uses a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem which, on an exam, is hard to quote. Is there any simple proofs to this?

Comment: No, it does not exist.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: I am fairly certain it is impossible to get this statement with anything simpler than application of Hahn-Banach (or it's corollary).

Comment: Yes, it relies on Hahn-Banach, what I am looking for is a more direct proof. Applying the proof of the corollary is a bit complicated, not to mention that I don't think I would be able to remember this proof during an exam.

Comment: You don't need a corollary of Hahn-Banach. You just need Hahn-Banach. And there is no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment no one knows the proof of this fact without sladgehammer like Hahn-Banach or something equivalent. On the other hand, to prove it is not only known but even impossible to find a direct proof is a difficult task. Such a proof that proof does not exist requires digging into foundations of mathematics.

Finally Hahn-Banach is so much important theorem that you must to learn it. This is one of three main theorems of functional analysis.

Comment: And what are the other two? You raised the question by your statement.

Comment: open mapping theorem and principle of uniform boundedness